# How to terminate a autosys job at particular time?

Tags: autosys

I want to terminate a autosys running job at a particular time of the day. Do we have any option available in autosys for that. I tried creating another job with `sendevent` command to kill the other job but it is failing. Can someone please help me out!

Answer (score 2):

Alternately, you can use term_run_time: XX (time in minutes) to terminate the job after it has run for XX minutes.

Answer (score 1):

**sendevent -E KILLJOB -J job name -T "mm/dd/yy HH:mm"(date and time is on the day and the time when you need to send this command )**

for esample i want the job to be placed into on hold on 15th dec 2013 at 14:30 then below is the command i ll run right awaya

**sendevent -E KILLJOB -J test_job -T "12/15/2013 14:30"**

if u want to abort the command i mean if you want to stop killing in then u can give

**sendevent -E KILLJOB -J test_job -T "12/15/2013 14:30" -U**

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer :)

Creating another job and putting `sendevent` command in it worked. Previously i didn't load the profile related to autosys environment that is why it was not working previously :)